# Transform the sentence "As soon as the child sees the mother, it begins to smile."

Tags: transformation

> As soon as the child sees the mother, it begins to smile.(Change it using "No sooner..... than").

Please help me to transform the sentence.

Comment: Please make an attempt yourself, and let us know where, specifically, you are having trouble.  A clue: you will need to use an auxiliary verb, a form of **do**, and there will be subject-verb inversion.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the child sees the mother, it begins to smile.(Change it using "No sooner..... than").
No sooner does the child see the mother than it begins to smile. (100% certain)

Answer (score -1):

```
"No sooner does the child see its mother than it begins to smile"
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not quite right!

Comment: so may I know the right one?

Comment: ["No sooner does the child see its mother than it begins to smile"](http://www.grammaring.com/hardly-scarcely-barely-no-sooner) :-)

Comment: @Araucaria "its mother"?! why not "his mother"

Comment: @Shannak It could be 'his' or 'her' or 'its'. Doesn't matter either way in terms of grammar. However, in this case we don't know which gender the child is.

Comment: @Shannak You may enjoy [this post here by the venerable F.E.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159009/is-is-it-a-girl-or-a-boy-really-calling-the-infant-an-it/159041#159041)

Comment: The syntax of this answer would be correct in the 18th and 19th centuries, and it can still be found written that way. But contemporary British and American speakers use the auxiliary **does** with inversion.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `No sooner does...  than it begins to smile.`   Ignore anyone who tells you so.  IThe page @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. links agrees with me:  "If ... no sooner [is] in the initial position, the subject and auxiliary are inverted", which is presumably what people are objecting to.   (Or - they are objecting to the tense.   The page says "the verb describing the earlier event is usually in the past perfect tense".   **But this is not always the case**.   With the present tense, there is a moving, narrative feel to the sentence - and this use occurs often.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - The inversion **is present** in the example.  Not inverted: `The child does no sooner see its mother than it begins to smile.`

Comment: Why did you edit your answer to make it incorrect? It would help if you explained how you transformed the sentence instead of just giving a different version. No-one can learn when spoon fed the answers.